# TSP (Travel Salesman problem) for multigraph

Tags: optimization, graph-theory

I'm trying to solve the Travel Salesman problem for multigraph.

Namely, I have a fully-connected graph with 2 oriented edges between every pair of nodes. The weight of the edge from x to y corresponds to the distance from x to y, but dist(x, y) != dist(y, x).

The number of nodes is around 40. Every node should be visited.

To my best understanding, simulated annealing and its variations do not work with this type of graph.

I would like to find some ideas/methods how to approach my problem.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I would try with linear programming, 40 nodes is not... excessive.

Comment: Would you be better asking on a more programming-oriented site as this does not seem a very statistical problem?

Comment: Agree that $40$ seems too large for simulation approach, too few of very many paths would be explored.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the basic assymetric TSP. You can try the LKH-3 algorithm ([http://webhotel4.ruc.dk/~keld/research/LKH-3/](http://webhotel4.ruc.dk/%7Ekeld/research/LKH-3/))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).